# RegEx to match numbers bigger than 0 on Grafana Value Mappings?

Tags: regex, grafana

I have a panel with a item that brings only numerical numbers, it can be from 0 to infinite.
I would like to use the following RegEx, that works on Regex101, to work like this:

RegEx: /^[1-9][0-9]*$/

0 - Will not match
12 - It will match

It's not working when using Value Mapping, on Grafana tho.
Here's how it is:

[image: Grafana Value Mapping]

If i use range to test it, let's say from 1 to 100, it works.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

**Edit**

Test with RegEx *^([1-9][0-9]*)$* :

[image: Test RegEx]

Didnt work for some reason. :|

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, did you try using a capture group `^([1-9][0-9]*)$`

Comment: I posted test i made with your syntax on question edit.

Comment: And perhaps `^.*([1-9][0-9]*).*$` with capture group 1 like `$1`

Comment: Same thing... It works on RegEx101 and other RegEx test sites tho. Maybe its a problem with Grafana itself...

Comment: @RaulChiarella remove the `/` characters?

Comment: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-rename-values-in-grafana-using-regex-based-value-mapping/53616/4 do you have a recent-enough version of Grafana and have you defined your value mapping to use a regex?

Comment: Yes. I saw that there is a issue opened for this at https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/41265. It looks like i have to tweak some settings there in order for colors to work.